# how to make and use db connection class using csharp?

Tags: c#, sql-server, class

I am new to C# and OOP as well and am making a DB class to connect with SQL Server. Could you help me create a connection function and explain how to reuse it in many forms? I have seen a function from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.aspx but am unsure how to use it in another form.

Regards,
Touseef

Comment: Is your question about reusing the creation function for a connection, or is it how to share one connection between different forms? Please clarify!

Answer (score 1):

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
//
    // First access the connection string, which may be autogenerated in Visual Studio for you.
    //
    string connectionString = "Write your sql connection string"
    //
    // In a using statement, acquire the SqlConnection as a resource.
    //
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        //
        // Open the SqlConnection.
        //
        con.Open();
        //
        // The following code shows how you can use an SqlCommand based on the SqlConnection.
        //
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 2 * FROM Dogs1", con))
        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            // process it
        }
        }
    }
```

**EDIT**
Use this link for detail tutorial
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/sql_in_csharp.aspx

Comment: How about without the concrete classes?  How to get the DbConnection instead to make code more database portable.

Answer (score 1):

Here are few code samples to get you going :

Establish the connection with SQL

```
string connectionString = "Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;";
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
con.Open();

//Database operations

con.Close();
```

Fetch the data from Database :

```
string queryString = "SELECT Column1, Column2 FROM TableName";
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(queryString, connection);

DataSet customers = new DataSet();
adapter.Fill(customers, "myTable");
```

Hope this gets you going.
All the best.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean DbConnection class, which is in the System.Data.Common namespace, then one way to use it in a C# program is as follows:

```
string CnnStr = "Data Source=local;Initial Catalog=dbTest;User Id=sa;pwd=1";
DbConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(CnnStr);
cnn.Open();
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of : [C#: Microsoft Enterprise Library: Data Access](http://www.programminghelp.com/programming/dotnet/c-microsoft-enterprise-library-data-access/)

To make connection on the second form you need to close the first connection and than create new one on the other from to get data.

Comment: private static void CreateCommand(string queryString,
    string connectionString)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(
               connectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
        command.Connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}

Comment: how to use this function in another class?

Comment: @Touseef Khan - you can check the document using google where you can find the examples easily related to this

Comment: Note: MS Enterprise Library: Data Access is not compatible for VS 2008 Express edition.  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6228